# Find, with proof, all functions $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N, f(n) + f(f(n)) = 2n+3$.

Tags: number-theory, functions

Find, with proof, all functions $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N, f(n) + f(f(n)) = 2n+3$.

Any ideas?

Comment: We can use the reccurence relation to solve this problem, right?

Comment: Does your definition of $\Bbb N$ have least element $0$ or $1$?